# See more webhook information for Github's api

Tags: github, webhooks

I have successfully set up a webhook for a github repo with the following request body:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  name: 'web',
  events: ['issues'],
  active: true,
  config: {
    url: 'http://12345678.ngrok.io',
    content_type: 'json',
  }
})
```

When an issue is edited on the repo, I get a request to my `ngrok` server, but I cannot find out further information about the issue event.

The best I can get is in the `request.headers` I have:

```
{ host: '12345678.ngrok.io',
accept: '*/*',
'user-agent': 'GitHub-Hookshot/1234567',
'x-github-event': 'issues',
'x-github-delivery': '12341234-12341234-12341234',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '7051',
'x-forwarded-for': '192.12.345.67' }
```

Can I also get than an issue was edited, what issue was edited and what it was edited to and from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webhook event will have this in the [payload](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads).  [Here](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#webhook-payload-example-10) is an example.

There are examples in [platform samples](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/hooks/ruby/configuring-your-server/server.rb) that show how to access the payload as JSON.

Comment: I have read the documentation. I however I have no `body` nor `payload` from my request.

Comment: Can you verify webhook are being sent using https://developer.github.com/webhooks/testing/#listing-recent-deliveries